# SQLite to MS SQL DateTime

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlite

I am using SQLite to store some date times.

My SQLite database has the following to create the table

```
String CREATE_METERREADS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_METERREADS + " ("
                + KEY_MYID + " INTEGER,"
                + KEY_MYNUMBER + " FLOAT,"
                + KEY_MYDATE + " TEXT" + ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL((CREATE_METERREADS_TABLE));
```

I am creating the date using the following and saving it in a class with a variable of type `String`:

```
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateRead = dateFormat.format(date);
```

I am then sending this through to SQL Server using a stored procedure as:

```
INSERT INTO MyData(ID, MYNumber, MYdate)
    VALUES (@MYID, @MYNUMBER, cast(@MYDATE as datetime))
```

For some reason the day and month are getting switched so when my date is created you can see the format above but when it is put into SQL server it is showing as `2019-07-05 08:51:07.000`  It is 7th of May when I am doing the insert.

Comment: Using `convert()` instead of `cast()` in SQL server will allow you to provide a third parameter which defines how your string should be read as a datetime, according to preexisting styles. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the generic cast function to convert from string, use the convert function that allows you to set the exact date format that you want to use for that conversion.

```
INSERT INTO MyData(ID, MYNumber, MYdate)
    VALUES (@MYID, @MYNUMBER, convert(datetime, @MYDATE, 120)
```

In your case, the format is the 120 (ODBC canonical) : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss

Here you have a complete list : 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: Hi @Marc Guillot,  just tried that with 103 (UK) and it didnt work

Comment: @Silentbob Sorry, I didn't read well your code, your string is in the 120 (ODBC) format, not 101 (US) format.

Comment: @Silentbob please realize that you are supposedly sending the string in the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss format.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by formatting issues of your date. Please try replacing

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

with

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```